# stack overflow error while executing JUnit test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, stack-overflow

The method I am writing unit test for has a method call that refers to a method In another class which is an abstract class. That method is called recursively, which is giving a stack overflow error when I execute my test case.

Below is the method under test

```
public void configure(Hashtable config) throws PipeBrokenException
  {
    // Configure the Pipe Element ...
    _source = (String) config.get(this.IMAGE_SOURCE);
    _destination = (String) config.get(this.IMAGE_DESTINATION);
    _printer = (XrayPrinterIf) config.get(this.PRINTER_INTERFACE);
    _configProvider = (AutoPrintConfigProvider) config.get(this.AUTOPRINT_CONFIG_PROVIDER);
     TraceLogger.getApplicationLogger().info("AutoPrintEndPoint Configure.. useTaskManager = " +useTaskManager);
    if(useTaskManager)
    {
        mgr = new AutoPrintTaskManager(this);
    }
    super.configure(config);//this method call gives a stack overflow error, when I comment this my test case runs fine.
  }
```

Below is the definition of the method call `super.configure(config);`, the class containing this method is an abstract class, and this method is called recursively endlessly giving me stack over flow error.

This method defined in `public abstract class AnAbstractClass`

```
public abstract class AnAbstractClass{
public void configure(Hashtable properties) throws PipeBrokenException
  {
    if( _nextNode != null)
    {
      _nextNode.configure(properties);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my JUnit test case, I am still an amateur at this and learning, please feel free to correct me wherever I am wrong and hopefully resolve the error I am facing.

```
@InjectMocks
    AutoPrintEndPoint autoPrintEndPoint = PowerMockito.spy(new AutoPrintEndPoint("pipeName")); //AutoPrintEndPoint is the class under test
@Test
    public void testConfigureHashtable() throws PipeBrokenException 
    {
      //  SmartPipeNode node=Mockito.mock(SmartPipeNode.class,Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

        AutoPrintConfigProvider autoPrintConfigProvider=Mockito.mock(AutoPrintConfigProvider.class); //AutoPrintConfigProvider is an interface
        XrayPrinterIf _printerIf=Mockito.mock(XrayPrinterIf.class);//XrayPrinterIf  is an interface
        Hashtable config=new Hashtable();
        config.put(AutoPrintEndPoint.IMAGE_SOURCE,"Source");
        config.put(AutoPrintEndPoint.IMAGE_DESTINATION,"Destination");
        config.put(AutoPrintEndPoint.PRINTER_INTERFACE,_printerIf);
        config.put(AutoPrintEndPoint.AUTOPRINT_CONFIG_PROVIDER,autoPrintConfigProvider);
        autoPrintEndPoint.configure("useTaskManager","yes");

        //Mockito.doNothing().when(autoPrintEndPoint).configure(config);


        autoPrintEndPoint.configure(config);
        String _source=Whitebox.getInternalState(autoPrintEndPoint, "_source");
        String _destination=Whitebox.getInternalState(autoPrintEndPoint, "_destination");
        System.out.println(_destination+"hello destination");
        System.out.println(_source+"here");
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you include the stack trace?

Comment: @NikolaStojiljkovic I have added the stack trace

Comment: Sorry, seems that I am too tired resp. too much in need for coffee. But OK, then you have to step back and provide a **real** [mcve]; as it is **absolutely** essential to understand **where** that autoPrintEndPoint` is coming from.

Comment: alright sorry about that. I will edit my post and mention it. I guess I did not notice that I omitted that detail.

Comment: `autoPrintEndPoint.configure("useTaskManager","yes");` this I call to go inside the if condition and to check if the variable `mgr` is initialized or not.

Comment: Yeah sorry I deleted my first comment, Didn't see the configure line below that. Can you explain what _nextNode is in your abstract class?

Comment: `private AnAbstractClass _nextNode = null;`

Comment: So in this case the super.configure method should do nothing? That's odd

Comment: If I could I would modify the implementation to work differently but unfortunately I can't. So I need to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PowerMockito you should be able to suppress any calls to methods in AnAbstractClass with:

```
PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn(AnAbstractClass.class));
```

Comment: I am getting an error in methodsDeclaredIn part of the syntax

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned its a static method of MemberMatcher

Comment: yes this works, but wouldn't it be violating the design of the implementation, should someone delete that method call in future, that I have suppressed, then my test case should fail since I am testing every possibility. If I suppress then my test case will pass even when the implementation is modified.

Answer (score 0):

`_nextNode` refers to `this`.

Add a check:

```
if (_nextNode != null && _nextNode != this) {
  _nextNode.configure(properties);
}
```

If circular links are possible, you'll have to keep track of all nodes visited in a Set and check that you're not visiting a node again.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the implementation.

Comment: Can you set `_nextNode`? Either by a setter or a constructor parameter?

Comment: yes I have a setter to set `_nextNode`. but even after I set it I am getting stack overflow error.

Comment: What do you set it to?

Comment: i set it to the mock object of the abstract class. The set method is also declared in the abstract class.

Comment: @AkhilVijayan And what do you set the mock object's nextNode to be? The mock object?

Comment: I set the object to the mock of the class which extends the abstract class. and created a thread to avoid repeated recursion, and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I created a thread to control the number of times the recursive call is taking place. and within the thread I have set the variable `_nextNode` with the mock object of the class which extends the abstract class that contains the recursive method. After the method is called the number of times specified then the variable `_nextNode` is set to null. I hope this answer will be useful.
below is the piece of code that I wrote to rectify the stack overflow error in my case

```
AutoPrintEndPoint autoPrintEndPointMock = Mockito.mock(AutoPrintEndPoint.class);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    autoPrintEndPoint.setNextNode(autoPrintEndPointMock); 
                }
                autoPrintEndPoint.setNextNode(null);

            }
        }.start();
        autoPrintEndPoint.configure(config);
```